# Trouble scripting inputs for set-Umserver cmd let

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I've writing some Exchange 2010 Unified Messaging automation scripts. I'm trying to automate the assoication of UM dial plans to UM Servers. The powershell command is :

```
[PS] E:\Scripts>Set-UmServer -id Exchange01 -DialPlans "test1", "test2"
```

When I try the following scripting solution:

```
[PS] E:\Scripts>$str = "`"test1`", `"test2`""
[PS] E:\Scripts>Set-UmServer -id Exchange01 -DialPlans $str
```

I get an error:

```
The UM dial plan "test1", "test2" doesn't exist.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Set-UmServer], ManagementObjectNotF
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 7AF43AA1,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Tasks.UM.SetUMServer
```

My feeling is that I'm handling the variable incorrectly and the variable is swapping in ""test1", "test2"" rather than "test1", "test2".

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

regards

Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overworking it. :-)  Try this:

```
$str = "test1", "test2"
Set-UmServer -id Exchange01 -DialPlans $str
```

Comment: Thanks Keith. This gave me the hint I needed to fix the problem. 

I ended up using the following as it gave me more flexibility:
    $str = @()
    $str = $str + "test1"
    $str = $str + "test2"